# How to load a NetCDF-file into QGIS using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, netcdf

I have a CF-conform NetCDF-file which can be loaded into Quantum GIS (Version 1.8) by using the "Add Raster Layer"-button and subsequently choosing the file and the raster layers of interest. This works without problems. However, when trying to load the same file by following [these steps](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) from the python cookbook, the layer remains invalid. I tried it using the console:

```
>>> fileName = "/path/to/file/myfile.nc"
>>> fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(fileName)
>>> baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
>>> rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
>>> rlayer.isValid()
False
```

When trying to add the layer to the map registry, it doesn't show up:

```
>>> QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
<qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x3715f80>
```

I tried the same procedure with a jpeg with world file and it works.

The cookbook mentions that GDAL might not support some formats. I don't know how to check this in QGIS, but since it works manually, I don't think that this is the problem.

Maybe, I have to specify the raster layer of interest somewhere in the code?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that netcdf can have several subdataset.See the scripts of the [netcdfbrowser plugin](https://github.com/etiennesky/netcdfbrowser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to gene mentioning the [netcdfbrowser plugin](https://github.com/etiennesky/netcdfbrowser/blob/master/netcdfbrowserdialog.py) (see the addLayer()-method in netcdfbrowserdialog.py) I managed to get it working. In case of NetCDF-files the file name is not sufficient to load a raster. We also need to include the variable of interest. The following works:

```
>>> uri='NETCDF:"/path/to/file/myfile.nc":myvariable'
>>> rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri,'mylayername')
>>> rlayer.isValid()
True
>>> QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
<qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x38f5560>
```

The layer shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Crayfish Plugin:
First you need to install the plugin. And then:

```
    import qgis.utils
    cf = qgis.utils.plugins["crayfish"]
    cf.loadMesh('some/file.nc', '.nc')
    cf.dock.currentLayerChanged()
```

Currently, you need to select the CRS interactively.

Comment: As commented on one of your other answers  - While we do not forbid advertising products which solve the specific problem described in a thread, it is generally recommended to provide specific details and - if appropriate - code/screenshots to back up your claims rather than a couple of links to some product website

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your answer to update it with this information and to add a disclosure statement as per http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior