# Open a NetCDF file with multiple time step on QGIS (using Python console)

Tags: qgis, python, netcdf

[How to load a NetCDF-file into QGIS using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/how-to-load-a-netcdf-file-into-qgis-using-python) explains well how to load a NetCDF with PyQgis. However, it did not help me to choose among all the available time steps.

Is there a way to import a specific time step (or all of them) when I am loading layers from a NetCDF file?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 3.x series contains build-in [Time Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgDg5cRwPRw&t=3261s) and native [Mesh Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html). [Crayfish](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/crayfish/) plugin can be used to show plots and extra processing algorithms for mesh layers.

---

[Crayfish](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/crayfish/) plugin from version 2.2 is suitable for loading and displaying time varying mesh in QGIS 2.x.

After installation of the [plugin from the official QGIS repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/crayfish/), one can use "Add Crayfish Layer button" [image] to [load](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/crayfish/wiki) NetCDF file.